# Where is Host in cosmosdb settings azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I need to pass the host address to a python client for accessing cosmosdb , but where can i find host and account key in cosmosdb resource?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Host is the endpoint that you need to pass while making a client, You can find the from **`Settings -> Keys -> PRIMARY CONNECTION STRING`** when you click on your cosmosDB resource.

**`AccountEndpoint`** is the url that you need to pass

Answer (score 1):

You could find your `url` and `key` or `CONNECTION STRING` on the portal.

[image]

And you need to use them when you create cosmos db client.

***sample code:***

```
import pydocumentdb.document_client as document_client

config = {
    'ENDPOINT': 'https://***.documents.azure.com:443/',
    'MASTERKEY': '***',
    'DOCUMENTDB_DATABASE': 'db',
    'DOCUMENTDB_COLLECTION': 'coll'
};

# Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
client = document_client.DocumentClient(config['ENDPOINT'], {'masterKey': config['MASTERKEY']})
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: is not the same answer i posted above? strange that mine got downvoted

Comment: @Sajeetharan No idea. Maybe someone thought this case is off-topic.^^